# how to make form with dynamic list in flutter

Tags: android, forms, flutter, dart, dynamic-programming

I am trying to build a form in flutter with the dynamic list of chips where user can select the multiple category but i am unable to build it so as i am new to flutter i am not able to get it done that how can i get the static form fields and get the dynamic list of the chips in it.

I am trying to get it using the grid view but the grid view is repeating the the whole form with every chip and if i use the grid view with only chip i am not able to get the rest of the static field of the form.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Student form"),
      ),
      body:ExamGrid(),
    );
  }
```

Below is the ExamGrid:

```
class _ExamGridState extends State<ExamGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final loadedExams = Provider.of<StudentFormProvider>(context);
    final loadedExam = loadedExams.exams;

    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      itemCount: loadedExam.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
        String catname;
        final exam = loadedExam[i];
        if (i > 0) {
          catname = exam.catname;
        }
        if (exam.catname != catname) {
          //new SizedBox(height: 8);
          catname = exam.catname;
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 8, 8),
            child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(exam.catname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 17,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return FilterChip(
            label: Text(exam.examname),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide()),
            selected: exam.isselected,
            onSelected: (bool checked) {
              setState(() {
                exam.isselected = checked;
              });
            },
          );
        }
      },
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        //crossAxisCount: 1,
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        childAspectRatio: 4 / 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me what to do in such scenario as anything i am trying results to unexpected result. I want to have multiple static form list with the dynamic list of chips

Answer (score 0):

Have two widgets list in the class. One empty & one with all of the categories.
Show the user all of the categories and when the user tap on one category add it to the empty list and call setstate.

Comment: thanks for your response my concern is not about the user selected data. Rather my concern is about how to build a form with the static fields and dynamic list (which to be append from database).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this you need in my project there is a complete sample, you can select one chip or multiple

```
class CourseFilterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = "/CourseFilterScreen";

  _CourseFilterScreenState createState() => _CourseFilterScreenState();
}

class _CourseFilterScreenState extends State<CourseFilterScreen> {
  List title = [
    {'title': "React jsx", "value": "React jsx"},
    {'title': "English For Kids", "value": "English for kids"},
    {'title': "IELTS", "value": "IELTS"},
    {'title': "Egnlish", "value": "Egnlish"},
    {'title': "Flutter", "value": "Flutter"},
  ];

  List selectedReportList = List();
  String selectedReport = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: MultiSelectChip(
                reportList: title,
                onSelectionChanged: (selectedList) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedReportList = selectedList;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Text("${selectedReportList.join(",")}"),
            SingleSelectChip(
              reportList: title,
              onSelectionChanged: (selectItem) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedReport = selectItem;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(selectedReport),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MultiSelectChip extends StatefulWidget {
  final List reportList;
  final Function onSelectionChanged;

  MultiSelectChip({this.reportList, this.onSelectionChanged});

  @override
  _MultiSelectChipState createState() => _MultiSelectChipState();
}

class _MultiSelectChipState extends State<MultiSelectChip> {
  List selectedChoices = List();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
        children: widget.reportList
            .map((item) => (Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                    selectedColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    label: Text(item['title']),
                    selected: selectedChoices.contains(item['value']),
                    onSelected: (selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedChoices.contains(item['value'])
                            ? selectedChoices.remove(item['value'])
                            : selectedChoices.add(item['value']);
                        widget.onSelectionChanged(selectedChoices);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )))
            .toList());
  }
}

class SingleSelectChip extends StatefulWidget {
  final List reportList;
  final Function onSelectionChanged;

  SingleSelectChip({this.reportList, this.onSelectionChanged});

  @override
  _SingleSelectChipState createState() => _SingleSelectChipState();
}

class _SingleSelectChipState extends State<SingleSelectChip> {
  String selectedChoices = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
        children: widget.reportList
            .map((item) => (Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                    selectedColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    label: Text(item['title']),
                    selected: selectedChoices.contains(item['value']),
                    onSelected: (selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedChoices = item['value'];
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )))
            .toList());
  }
}
```